# Android, Activities and Threads

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new to Android and Java. I need some clarification about threads and their relationship with activities. I'm thinking for this case: A code running in background that can be visible for two activities. I don't know if this can be achieved using threads. From what I've read, there would be no problem using a service, but I'm not sure in the case of threads, so here my questions: If a thread is running in background, can it be "visible" for two or more activities? For example, the most basic sample about thread changes the text in some activity or update the value for a progress bar but, can this same thread be used to do the same in a second activity? Or I need to create a new thread for the second activity that do the same? Is a Service better approach for this case?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by visible? Please explain that thoroughly. And threads can't update any UI components, only the UI thread can.

Comment: I'm new to java so maybe visible is not the right term. Visible as meaning that a thread can be accessed from whether one or more activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a thread is running in background, can it be "visible" for two or
>   more activities?

If I understand "visible" as it can access these `Activity` instances then yes, why not? It's just another object.

> For example, the most basic sample about thread changes the text in
>   some activity or update the value for a progress bar but, can this
>   same thread be used to do the same in second activity?

Of course. Just keep in mind that the only thread that can draw UI is the UI thread (also called main or system thread). To do any UI update from any other thread you created, you need to call [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

> Is a Service better approach for this case?

If this thread is only for updating your app UI, then a background thread is the best solution. A Service will keep running after your app has closed and also you would need to do IPC to communicate app and service, which is slower and requires more code.

You also might consider using `AsyncTask` instead, it is more suitable for your case because some of its methods run directly on the UI thread (so you don't need `runOnUiThread`)

Comment: Thank you. And yes, I do have used the term "visible" as you understood.